# How do I use bufferedreader to read my text file and insert it in a Java stack

Tags: java, bufferedreader, stack

Heres my code im new to stacks and dont know how to implement them especially with the buffered reader. I dont know how to implement the stack code im new to programming . I have to write a program that'll reverse the direction read from my txt file and print them out.

```
try
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GoingThere.txt"));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
           line.replace("West","East");
           line.replace("East","West");
           line.replace("North", "South");
           line.replace("South", "North");      
           line = in.readLine();
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{ 
  System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
}
catch(IOException e)
{ 
  System.out.println("IO Exception Found.");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the question? I dont' see any stack in you code.

Comment: anyway the code                     line.replace("West","East");
                    line.replace("East","West");
will change "East" to "West" but "West" stays "West" because it get changed two times.

Comment: @manu-fatto: worse than that... these lines do nothing because the replacement result is the return value, which isn't used at all. Remember that strings are immutable in Java.

Comment: Furthermore, catching an `Exception` and printing `IO Exception Found` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The Same of your Codes but I Added The Stack  Hope you Understand it 
The implementation of stack :
Stack <String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push(String);
stack.pop();

here is the  Same Example :

       Stack <String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    try
        {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("GoingThere.txt"));
        String line = in.readLine();
        String a,b,c,d;
        while(line != null)
        {
        System.out.println(a=line.replace("West","East"));
        System.out.println(b=line.replace("East","West"));
        System.out.println(c=line.replace("North", "South"));
        System.out.println(d=line.replace("South", "North"));

        stack.push(a);
        stack.push(b);
        stack.push(c);
        stack.push(d);    
        System.out.println("----------------- Stack Pushed -----------------");
        line = in.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Pop is Begin :");

        while(!stack.isEmpty()){

            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        { 
          System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        { 
          System.out.println("IO Exception Found.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves me deeply confused.  However, from your code and the name of the text file I think I can extrapolate what you're trying to do.  I'm guessing that you have a school assignment which gives you a list of directions for A -> B.  You are required to reverse these directions using a stack to give B -> A.  Based on that assumption, try:

```
Stack st = new Stack();
while (line != null) {
    st.push(line);
    line = in.readLine();
}
```

You can then use `st.pop()` to recover your lines from the stack in reverse order.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about anything in the question.  It's far too vague.  The OP can swap in their own Stack implementation as needed.